# ¿Qué instrucción debería usar para que un archivo html luego de ser ejecutado devuelva el control al archivo que lo invocó?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Usando java 8, con Spring Boot y Thymeleaf: tengo 2 archivos html (páginas) que invocan el mismo archivo html que muestra una página, pero quisiera para no tener que duplicar el archivo, que al click del botón "Volver", regrese a  la página anterior. Ambos archivos acceden a una clase controler .java diferente, donde un método, invoca al tercer archivo html. En dicho archivo, tengo el siguiente código, pero solo permite que regrese a una de las páginas y yo necesito que sea cualquiera de las dos que lo invoque regrese a ella.
El código en el tercer archivo para volver es:

```
<a th:href="@{/dev/iniciod}" class="btn">Volver</a>
```

¿Alguien me podría ayudar? Soy nueva en el lenguaje. Desde ya agradecida...

Answer (score 0):

Desde tu .html indica hacia que metodo del Controller.java quieres ir, por ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" th:action=" @{/empleado/new/submit}">
```

Esto se irá a tu Controller.java donde tengas esa dirección, en mi caso:

```
@PostMapping("/empleado/new/submit")
//                                  @ModelAttribute -> sirve para obtener objetos desde un formulario HTML y vincularlo automáticamente a un objeto Java correspondiente.
public String nuevoEmpleadoSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("empleadoForm") Empleado nuevoEmpleado, BindingResult bindingResult, 
        //una vez que hemos añadido el empleado, obtenemos ese archivo así
        //file es como hemos llamado al campo en el formulario(name = "file")
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String sitio = "";
    //si el empleado introducido tiene errores, lo mandamos de nuevo al form.html, para que los corrija
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        sitio = "form";
    }
    //sino tiene erores
    else {
        //si subio una imagen como avatar
        if(file.isEmpty() == false) {
            //Lógica de almacenamiento de fichero
            //utilizamos el método store(que almacena el fichero y además le cambia el nombre) que nos devuelve el nuevo nombre del fichero ya almacenado
            String avatar = storageService.store(file, nuevoEmpleado.getId());
            //vamos a ponerle al empleado la imagen de la siguiente forma:
            nuevoEmpleado.setImagen(
                    MvcUriComponentsBuilder. //Nos permite crear una uri
                    fromMethodName //la hace usando un método, en nuestro caso anotado con la ruta /files/filename
                    (EmpleadoController.class, "serveFile", avatar).build().toUriString()   //llamamos al metodo que tenemos hecho más abajo(serveFile)
                                                                                                                                  //y le pasamos como parámetro a ese metodo el nombre de como
                                                                                                                                  //se guardó la imagen, este metodo nos devolverá esa imagen,
                                                                                                                                  //como recurso
                                                                                                                                  //y además usaremos todo eso para construit la uri(que es un identificador único de un recurso en la web)
                    );
            System.out.println("uri: " + MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(EmpleadoController.class, "serveFile", avatar).build().toUriString());
        }
        //añadimos ese empleado a nuestra base de datos
        servicio.add(nuevoEmpleado);
        //enviamos al usuario a la pagina donde salen todos los empleados
        sitio = "redirect:/empleado/list";
    }
    return sitio;
}
```

Ese código guarda en la bdd un usuario, si el empleado tiene errores lo enviamos a form.html de nuevo, sino a "redirect:/empleado/list"

Por lo que el flujo seria:
form.html donde tenemos un formulario que crea un usuario, cuando le da al boton de submit se va a -> Controller.java al método especificado en el form.html(en este caso la dirección que se especifica es "@{/empleado/new/submit}") -> Desde este método haces la lógica de negocio (en mi caso compruebo que el usuario este correcto y lo guardo en mi bdd) y una vez hecha la lógica de negocio lo enviamos a donde nos interese, en mi caso a list.html para ver si ese empleado se introdujo